# I need to make my bot in tic tac toe turn off after a certain amount of moves

Tags: javascript, tic-tac-toe

So I need this code to be stopped I have a variable but I don't know how to make a line of code to stop the function Like I need it to stop after 8 moves have been done

```js
var movecount = (turn >= 8);
var killbot = 
    if (movecount) {
    killbot;
}
function easy_bot() {

    var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
    if (!checkWinner(turn))
        while (board[rnum].style.backgroundImage != "") {
            console.log("104");
            rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
        }
    board[rnum].style.backgroundImage = "url('X.gif')";

    turn = "O";
```

Comment: Hint: See the documentation on [`break`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp)

Answer (score 0):

U could use [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) to end function execution.

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate more on the problem? Analyzing the easy_bot () function, it is good and stops after finding an empty space to place the "x" and then turns to "0"